# SOAP UI - Not able to authenticate REST API

Tags: soapui

I am trying to request a response from the following REST API

```
Request - POST
URL - http://auldslap540.sit.biz:9189/ws/Retrieve-RequestSummary/1.0
```

The headers passed are( I got these debugging from the log ):

```
SOAPAction: retrieveSummary
User-Agent: Axis2
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=UTF-8
```

Authentication is `Basic` and passing the username/password

passing an XML request and the response is:

```
DEBUG: Attempt 1 to execute request
DEBUG:Sending request: POST /ws/Retrieve-RequestSummary/1.0 HTTP/1.1
DEBUG:Receiving response: HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
DEBUG:Connection can be kept indefinitely
DEBUG:Target requested authentication
DEBUG:Authorization challenge processed
DEBUG:Authentication scope: BASIC <any realm> @auldslap540.sit.biz:9189
DEBUG:auldslap540.sit.biz:9189 requires authentication with the realm 'null'
DEBUG:Found credentials
DEBUG:Attempt 2 to execute request
DEBUG:Sending request: POST /ws/Retrieve-RequestSummary/1.0 HTTP/1.1
DEBUG:Receiving response: HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
DEBUG:Connection can be kept indefinitely
DEBUG:Target requested authentication
DEBUG:Authorization challenge processed
DEBUG:Authentication scope: BASIC <any realm> @auldslap540.sit.biz:9189
DEBUG:Authentication failed
DEBUG:Connection closed
```

This is working fine from Java code as per the logs. But from SOAP UI, I get the above error.

Any help would be appreciated.

Regards
R

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try changing the authentication type to NTLM instead of Basic. If not, please try that once.

Additionally if you have not specified login credentials in the Rest Request test case step for Rest API, please try specifying the login credentials in the Rest Request step as well.